# Unknown component dynamic importing error in nextjs App Router

Tags: next.js, dynamic, app-router

Dynamic Importing of an unknown component is not working in vercel deployment after I migrated from Page to App router. Everything works fine when i build on my local system.

This is the code i used for the importing purpose.

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

export function getDynamicComponent(location) {
  return dynamic(() => import(../../websites/${location}));
}
```

After the migration an error started throwing only in production mode.
TypeError: L.current is null this is the log in the web console.

I will attach an image of the full console log.

[image]

By the way the build process is completing successfully in vercel and the problem only exists when i open the page with dynamic import.